# How to set DeserializationProblemHandler when using a WebTarget?

Tags: jersey

I'd like to log the unknown incoming JSON properties when calling a Restful service using WebTarget.  The return values should be in JSON.  I'm thinking setting a DeserializationProblemHandler to my ObjectMapper.  But where and how to set that?

```
WebTarget tgt = ...;
DummyResult result = tgt.request()
    .post(Entity.entity(callParam, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE),
    DummyResult.class);
```

If I have an instance of a ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.addHandler(MyDeserializationProblemHandler.getInstance());
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, just separate the big call.

```
javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation invocation = tgt.request()
    .buildPost(Entity.entity(callParam, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
String response = invocation.invoke(String.class);

// then use ObjectMapper to serialize
String result = om.readValue(response, DummyResult.class);
```

Now 'MyDeserializationProblemHandler' will log all the unknown fields by names and values, so I can notify the callers for any possible errors.